# Sinatra and Haml: strange behaviour after gem update

Tags: sinatra, haml

I've made a site using Haml and Sinatra. After the update (I guess it was after that) the site didn't work any more; here is a minimal example:

/app.rb:

```
require 'rubygems' if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9'
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'

get "/" do
  haml :index
end
```

/views/layout.haml

```
!!!
%html{ :xmlns => "http://ww.w3.org/1999/xhtml", :lang => "en", "xml:lang" => "en" }
  %head
    %title test
  %body
    = yield
```

/view/index.haml

```
%p test
```

and it throws me the following exception:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.2/lib/tilt/template.rb in initialize
    raise ArgumentError, "file or block required" if (@file || block).nil?

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.0.a/lib/sinatra/base.rb in new
    template.new(path, 1, options)

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.0.a/lib/sinatra/base.rb in block in compile_template
    template.new(path, 1, options)

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.2/lib/tilt.rb in fetch
    @cache[key] ||= yield

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.0.a/lib/sinatra/base.rb in compile_template
    template_cache.fetch engine, data, options do

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.0.a/lib/sinatra/base.rb in render
    template = compile_template(engine, data, options, views)

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.0.a/lib/sinatra/base.rb in haml
    render :haml, template, options, locals
```

I haven't really found a way to fix it, does anyone know how to interpret it?

Answer (score 2):

I get the same error with Sinatra 1.3.0.a (the version you're using, which I assume is a release candidate and not a full release), but updating to the current latest (1.3.0.e) fixes it, as does downgrading to the latest stable release (1.2.6). So your answer is upgrade or downgrade.

You can load a specific version of a gem using:

```
gem "sinatra", "=1.2.6"
```

before you call `require "sinatra"`, or you could look into using [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) (which uses the same syntax).